# React/Redux fire action immediately after first action completes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise, redux-thunk

I'm using some react/redux boilerplate and I'm trying to find a way to dispatch an action when the first one completes.

It's been a while since I've used redux so I'm at a loss for why this configuration for dispatching an action after another one won't work.

In this example, imagine actionTwo() is basically exactly the same as actionOne() and I just want it to be fired right after the actionOne promise
returns.

My question is, why does this configuration have problems and what is the right way to fire actions immediately after actions complete?

```
import axios from 'axios';
import type { ThunkAction } from '../types';

export const actionOne = (value1, value2): ThunkAction => dispatch =>
  axios
   .post('/api/route', {
     params: {
       username: value1,
       password: value2
     },
      credentials: 'include' 
    })
    .then(response => {

      dispatch(actionTwo());  //this dispatch either fails completely or takes a long time to start

      dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_ACTIONONE_SUCCESS', //this dispatch fires immediately always
        data: response
      });

    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_ACTIONONE_FAIL',
        data: err
      });
    });
```

Comment: Hot take: your ActionTwo should be responsible for calling the second dispatch. Either put it directly in or feed the second dispatch as a callback to the first.

Comment: Use asyn and await with your dispatch

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev what if you need one action to fire immediately after another without any user input? Can you link to an example of the pattern you're describing?

Comment: My guess is that actionTwo doesn't fire an action until a request is resolved.

Comment: @dominic,yes you have it right, actionTwo looks exactly like actionOne and even for the sake of the example calls an actionThree

Comment: An example is already described in the composition section of `redux-thunk` documentation: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#composition

Comment: If actionTwo() is like actionOne(), then it will have its own dispatch statements and will return a promise. If that is genuinely the case, then the line `dispatch(actionTwo())` is most likely incorrect. You probably want `return action2().then(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you `return` the promise in actionone, you can wait for it and then call actiontwo:

```
export const actionOne = (value1, value2): ThunkAction => dispatch =>
  return axios.post('/api/route', { // return added here
     params: {
```

then when dispatching:

```
const results = await dispatch( actionone )
dispatch( actiontwo )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your Action One in a promise and fire off Action Two when that promise returns.

Answer (score 0):

A thunk action is a little different in that it return a function which dispatches actions. When you dispatch to a thunk it will not immediately call/log an action unless you have one there outside the request promise (see code below). So the first action you should see in your example is `FETCH_ACTIONONE_SUCCESS` since you didn't add a `FETCH_ACTIONONE_REQUESTED` action at the top of your thunk.

```
const thunkAction = () => dispatch => {
  // If you have one here you will see it straight away (if it's a normal action).
  dispatch({ type: 'FetchingThatThing' });

  axios(...).then(data => {
    // In your action this is the first action you would see once the request
    // is finished since you don't have the first one ^
    dispatch({ type: 'FinishedFetchingThatThing' });
  });
};
```